# What's the use of export intelliJ idea code style in Json file where only xml code style schema can be used

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

User can export the code format configuration into a schema file. The schema file can be exported into **XML** and **Json** format. But intelliJ idea can only import the code style schema in **XML**.

If only XML format can be accepted as the code schema, why intellij idea provide the function to export the schema file in Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Export to JSON** is just a way to export all code style settings in some readable format that can later be edited/transformed/translated into something useable by other tools. e.g. Uncrustify , AStyle , JSCS etc.

IDEA itself can't read such settings, you can only import XML produced by **Export > IntellijIDEA code style XML**

Comment: thanks, I need to create a one xml code schema file to take care of multiple language format. Export all settings into JSON looks fine. Is there any tool to translate the JSON file into the intelliJIDEA code style xml?

Comment: I'm not aware of any; but, if you need a file in  intelliJIDEA code style xml format, why not just using **Export > IntellijIDEA code style XML**?

Comment: I think the biggest issue is it is not able to export multple settings to a XML schema file. I need to combine different code format and exported it into one single file, the java part is come from IntelliJ-java-google-style.xml the Scala and Python part is come from the conflagration by my own. Does intelliJIDEA able to do that?

Comment: no, it can only export settings from the current schema